# communication between microservices on separated servers

Tags: rest, ipc, communication

What kind of channel/protocol do you use to communicate between microservices on two separated servers? 
For one-way communication some queue is enough, but what if we need synchronous 2-way (which we should avoid) communication between microservices?
Do you use http protocol? How look performance of your "channels"?
Please share your experience in this subject.
What in case when one service is in Java and another one in .net?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your description, sounds like you are wanting/needing to implement a message broker. Your services then talk in a pub/sub scenario to each other. Ideally each of the services are not coupled in anyway.

The comment about avoiding async communication between microservices I would have to disagree.  Async communication is actually the desired method of communication for setting up a microservice.  In context of inter-service communications.

Examples:

[RabbitMQ](http://www.rabbitmq.com/)

[Apache ActiveMQ](http://activemq.apache.org/amqp.html)